# Problems creating admin configuration for custom module

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've been trying to create a *very* simple extension. Essentially I only need to be able to store images / text with it, and then echo it on the front-end. Now I've tried following different guides online and they seem to be missing important elements because either the extensions don't show in the admin area, or I get an error.

For example, I followed http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/ to the 'T', and I get the following error in the admin area when going to Configuration:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Inchoo_Mymodule_Helper_Data' not found in /home/apndev/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546
```

Is there a better way of going about this or does a tutorial exist that is current and works? Perhaps I'm missing a vital step somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to learn the most by wrinting modules. I think it is the right approach. In the tutorial a helper is registered with

```
<helpers>
   <mymodule>
      <class>Inchoo_Mymodule_Helper</class>
   </mymodule>
</helpers>
```

but the class is missing. That's what this exception is about. Try to create it in

app/code/local/Inchoo/Mymodule/Helper/Data.php

```
class Inchoo_Mymodule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using a module creator in the beginning and build on that. Here are a few of them:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/utilities/developer-tools/ultimate-modulecreator-8949.html - this one is mine :). It let's you create your entities in a similar way you create a table using phpmyadmin
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/utilities/developer-tools/modulecreator.html this is a minimalist module creator, very good for learning purposes.
- http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/ - this is a pretty complex one and it has the advantage of being online, so you don't have to install any extension.

Answer (score 0):

Fatal error: Class 'Inchoo_Mymodule_Helper_Data' not found in /home/apndev/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546

mean that you need to create Data.php file under
app/code/local/Inchoo/Mymodule/Helper/Data.php